How to fold/normalize ligature characters in C# for string comparisons
I am exploring some of the more esoteric aspects of string comparisons at the moment (I went down a bit of a rabbit hole and there doesn't seem to be an end in sight!).
I'd like to know how to compare a string containing characters with ligatures to a canonical non-ligature version (imagine an application for French language learning that lets the user type in oeuf or œuf interchangeably). I think this is called 'folding', but I could be wrong.
I've tried normalizing my strings using NFKD, which I thought would decompose the character into its constituent parts, but only some Unicode codepoints support decomposition. (Of course, my example character 'œ' doesn't, which resulted in much hair-pulling.)
For example:
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

// This character does not support decomposition.
string str1 = "\u0153"; // œ (LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE)
string str2 = "oe";
string str1norm = str1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);

Console.WriteLine(str1norm.IsNormalized()); // True
Console.WriteLine(str1norm.Equals(str2));   // False
Console.WriteLine(str1norm.Length);         // 1

// This character supports decomposition.
str1 = "\uFB06"; // ﬆ (LATIN SMALL LIGATURE ST)
str2 = "st";
str1norm = str1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);

Console.WriteLine(str1norm.IsNormalized()); // True
Console.WriteLine(str1norm.Equals(str2));   // True
// (Non-normalized comparison.) True in most locales, but not all (see below)
Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)); 
Console.WriteLine(str1norm.Length);         // 2

References for the two Unicode characters:

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0153

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FB06


If only some ligatures are decomposable, I have a couple of questions:

How do I determine this without manually checking through all the Unicode code points?
Can I do a string comparison to a canonical version of the string without having to create a dictionary of all the non-decomposable characters and their expanded forms? I mean, I like typing, but not that much.
(Bonus round.) Why are some multi-character code points decomposable (like the ligature 'st' example), and some not? Is there something special about characters like 'œ'?

Edit: I've done some further research, and characters like 'œ' or the German 'sharp s' are thought of as distinct characters, not composites. They represent the current usage in those languages, even if historically things may have developed from different representations. Unicode takes into account current usage, so marking them as non-decomposable makes sense.
As a final illustration of my "what-on-earth-is-going-on?" mindset at the moment, 'ﬆ' is equivalent to 'st' without normalizing in 862 locales on my PC, with the string comparison failing in only 7, with those failure locales being:

aa (Afar language)
aa-DJ (Afar - Djibouti)
aa-ER (Afar - Eritrea)
aa-ET (Afar - Ethiopia)
en-US-POSIX (US English POSIX settings)
ssy (Saho language)
ssy-ER (Saho - Eritrea)

This is all very interesting, but the sheer apparent arbitrariness of it all is a bit overwhelming :)  As far as I know, Afar and Saho have Latin-based written forms, but I assume their Unicode code pages are less popular and may just lack the entries for ligatures which are present in others.
Finally finally, the single-character 'ﬆ' and its decomposed form 'st' are equal in the .NET Invariant culture, but only if case is ignored:
//...continuing from prior code...
Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));           // False
Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)); // True

This is puzzling because both strings are lowercase.
(I know, "Just normalize your string and forget you ever saw this, Dave." But I still think it's interesting to know why this happens.)
Thanks for your time.

I really don't have an answer to any of your "why" questions, other than "because". But you may be interested in transliteration instead of normalisation. Or check out their mapping and roll your own dictionary.

a.) NLS based code (Old .Net Framework) my behave differently here then ICU based code (newer .Net Core code). b.) The overloads with CompareOptions may fit better for you then the ones with StringComparison for example your french example work when Comparing this way String.Compare("oeuf", "œuf", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-fr"), CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace)

If you are actually using the ICU base system that does all of this comparing stuff check also https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/scompare to see if what you need is actually possible. Common Unicode is nice but what ICU actually does is more relevant here.

"folding" means a process that treats two different things as the same thing, to eliminate differences, to map a set of items into a set of equivalence classes. Unicode normalization forms are a type of folding; a function toLowercase() would be a type of folding.

@NPras - thank you! Using a transliteration/romanisation library looks like a good avenue for me to explore next. Having a ready-made solution will certainly save a lot of typing!

@Ralf - Thanks so much for the tips and the link. Yes, I'm using ICU under the most recent .NET version.
It does look like experimenting with String.Compare's CompareOptions is a route forward. 'oe' is equal to 'œ' under the InvariantCulture, too, if IgnoreNonSpace is used, which is interesting. Now to try this with those other 4,000 ligature characters... ;)

@PeterConstable Thanks for the definition - that sounds pretty much exactly what it is that I'm exploring. Knowing the accurate terminology is going to be very useful.
